# Passing parmeter to js function

Tags: javascript

I have this code which populates a table. The very last column of the table is a button which has an onclick function. I am trying to pass a variable but I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined
```

I know what that error means but I don't know how to fix it.

```
if(obj[i].book_status =="Found"){
 txt += "<tr><td>"+obj[i].Member_ID+"</td><td>"+obj[i].FirstName+"</td>" + 
          "<td>"+obj[i].LastName+"</td><td>" +obj[i].IssueDate+"</td><td>"+
          obj[i].DueDate+"</td><td><button  class='btn btn-primary' onClick='getID(obj[i].Member_ID);'>CheckIn</button></td></tr>";
 }
}
```

Comment: what is the loop function?

Comment: could u post a [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net), that will help in debugging.

Comment: Do you mean where is the loop function? I just did not put it here becaue I did not find including it necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're generating a string of HTML with JavaScript embedded in it. When that JavaScript is executed, it will be in a completely different scope, one where `obj` **isn't** defined.

Don't work with the DOM by mashing strings of HTML into it. Use standard DOM methods (like createElement and appendChild). Then you can add an event listener and preserve your scope.

You could also store the relevant data on the element to avoid having to create a closure.

For example, something along the lines of:

```
var row, td, item, button;

item = obj[i];

if (item.book_status == "Found") {
    row = document.createElement("tr");

    cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.Member_ID));
    row.appendChild(cell);

    cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.FirstName));
    row.appendChild(cell);

    cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.LastName));
    row.appendChild(cell);

    cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.IssueDate));
    row.appendChild(cell);

    cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.DueDate));
    row.appendChild(cell);

    cell = document.createElement("td");
    button = document.createElement("button");
    button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("CheckIn"));
    button.classList.add("btn");
    button.classList.add("btn-primary");
    button.setAttribute("data-id", item.Member_ID);
    button.addEventListener("click", getIDHandler)
    row.appendChild(cell);

    function getIDHandler(event) {
        getID(this.getAttribute("data-id"));
    }

    SOMETHING.appendChild(row);

}
```

Comment: can you give an example? I am quite new to to js.

Comment: For the time being, if I decide to go with the string approach, is there a way to fix this issue or no?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a string value at the `onclick` inline handler, as you have to concatenate it:

```
"</td><td><button  ... onClick='getID('"+ obj[i].Member_ID +"');'>...</td></tr>";
```

Comment: @Quentin right! i get it. that can be alphanumeric.

Comment: But it can't be an object or include a `'` character (which isn't likely given the name, but highlights the fragility of mashing together strings to generate JavaScript embedded in HTML).